# "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function", but this is not true. [Warning ProjectEuler: 4]

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror

I have got a Javascript function which does a ton of calculations (not my main problem ;P) and I'm attmepting to call it, using both a button with an `onClick=""` property and both by just calling it inside the code.

main.js :

```
var val;
var palindromes = [];

function count() {  
    for (var i = 100; i <= 999; i++) { //for loop multiplies all 3 digit values together
        for (var j = 100; j <= 999; j++) {
            val = j+i;
            var valString = val.toString();
            if (valString.splice(0,1) == valString.splice(5,6) || valString.splice(1,2) == valString.splice(4,5) || valString.splice(2,3) == valString.splice(3,4)) { // If statement to check for palindromes
                palindromes.push(valString);
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(arr.reduce(function(previous,current){ return previous > current ? previous:current })); // show me the largest palindrome!
}
count(); // here I am calling the function from the code
```

my HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Problem #4</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="main.js"></script>

<button onclick="count()">Click Me!</button> <!-- This is my button that will call the function -->

</body>
</html>
```

Again, I am not really afraid how bad the code is, but more interested why get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (anonymous function)`
I am using Google Chrome Version: 39.0.2171.95 (Official Build) m and Javascript: V8 3.29.88.17. Not sure if that helps or anything. Thanks in advance ;).

PS: I have also tried having the code in the script tags, but this has not helped

Comment: Where do you set the variable `arr`?

Comment: Which line is the error on? Have you used the Javascript debugger to look at the variables? What does `valString.splice` return?

Comment: A quick look at the console gives the break point at your `if` statement. One of my first hard lessons when learning javascript is that errors are silent and must be looked up. Although you may not like it in the beginning you learn very much from just looking at the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (valString.splice(0,1) == valString.splice(5,6) || valString.splice(1,2) == valString.splice(4,5) || valString.splice(2,3) == valString.splice(3,4)) { // If statement to check for palindromes
```

There is no `splice` method on strings, although one does exist on arrays.

Comment: He's probably looking for `substr`.

Comment: Or maybe `slice`. Strings have lots of methods.

Comment: They're all 1-character slices, so `.charAt(n)` would probably be the best.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I was doing stuff with arrays most of the time, so I got confused with the different abilities of cutting them up. @Barmer thanks for `.charAt(n)` will see if this will work ;)